# Cyclejs Read/write websocket driver?

Tags: websocket, cyclejs

I'm new to cyclejs and I'm looking for websocket support and I don't see any (apart from the read only websocket driver from the docs and some 0.1.2 node side npm package).

Am I supposed to create my own driver or am I missing something?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you looked at [cycle-websocket](https://github.com/Orbmancer/cycle-websocket)?

Comment: On its github it says:
"Node, browser ?

This was built and tested for node, not tested in the browser but it should work. Keep me in touch if it's working or not !"
=> not really thought for browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this page help you?

https://cycle.js.org/drivers.html

Specifically the example code mentioned:

```
function WSDriver(/* no sinks */) {
  return xs.create({
    start: listener => {
       this.connection = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:4000');
       connection.onerror = (err) => {
          listener.error(err)
       }
       connection.onmessage = (msg) => {
         listener.next(msg)
       }
    },
    stop: () => {
      this.connection.close();
    },
 });
}
```

If you add a sink this should be a write and read driver. From their documentation:

> Most drivers, like the DOM Driver, take sinks (to describe a write) and return sources (to catch reads). However, we might have valid cases for write-only drivers and read-only drivers.
>
> For instance, the one-liner log driver we just saw above is a write-only driver. Notice how it is a function that does not return any stream, it simply consumes the sink msg$ it receives.
>
> Other drivers only create source streams that emit events to the main(), but don’t take in any sink from main(). An example of such would be a read-only Web Socket driver, drafted below:

Comment: thx :) I'm pretty new to it and I feared it would be harder, but actually since I'm playing more with it it looks doable :)

Comment: Good to hear you will get it working. Hope your app will conquer the world. :D