# Update source and sink dynamically in cycle js?

Tags: redux, cyclejs

I'm writing a very simple app using redux-cycle, with 3 elements:

1. A text field to input url
2. A "connect" button to connect to a websocket end point
3. An output panel to show incoming messages

I have written a very simple websocket driver based on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/42926532/842860

The wire up code is like this:

```js
const cycleMiddleware = createCycleMiddleware();
const {makeActionDriver} = cycleMiddleware;

function main(sources) {
    return {
        ACTION: sources.WEBSOCKET // The websocket driver emits commands which are consumed by reducers
    }
}

const store = createStore(
    reducer, // Update redux state
    applyMiddleware(cycleMiddleware)
);

run(main, {
    WEBSOCKET: WSDriver("ws://localhost:3000/something"), // The initial connection string
    ACTION: makeActionDriver()
});
```

The question is how to make the websocket reconnect to another end point when the connect button is clicked?  Do I need to modify my websocket driver to capture the event and reconnect, or does cyclejs provide a way to dynamically update the source/sink?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the appropriate method would be to, indeed, update the `WSDriver` to take a `sink$` as input. This `sink$` could contain the url you want to connect to.

Your driver would look like this

```
function WSDriver(endpoint$) {
  var activeConnection;
  return endpoint$
    .map(endpointUrl => xs.create({
      start: listener => {
       activeConnection = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:4000');
       /* no change here */
      },
      stop: () => {
        activeConnection.close();
      }
    }))
    .flatten() // it's a stream of stream, so we need to flatten it
}
```

On the `app` side you would need to change this

```
run(main, {
    WEBSOCKET: WSDriver(), // < no initial connection
    ACTION: makeActionDriver()
});
```

And in your `main`

```
function main(sources) {
    return {
        ACTION: sources.WEBSOCKET,
        WEBSOCKET: newConnection$.startWith("ws://localhost:3000/something")
    }
}
```

Given that the `newConnection$` comes from the click events on the button.

Hope it helps